# How in laravel do the automatic assignment of id in linked tables?

Tags: laravel-5

I have 3 tables linked with hasOne(). Modeel User.php linked with Profile.php
Profile.php linked with Country.php and Profile.php linked with City.php.

In the Profiles table have user_id foreign key. In the Countrys table have profile_id foreign key. And in the Citys table have profile_id foreign key.

How i can do correctly auto fill this foreign keys with user id.

Now i do so in RegistersUsers.php

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $profile = new Profile;
    $profile->user_id = $user_id; 
    $profile->save();

    $country = new Country;        
    $country->profile_id = $user_id;        
    $country->save();

    $city = new City;        
    $city->profile_id = $user_id;        
    $city->save();


    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

But I think that there is a way more correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relations `create` method to auto fill this foreign keys as:

```
$user = Auth::user();

$profile = $user->profile()->create(['name' => 'user_name'])
// assumes relation name is profile

$country = $profile->country()->create(['name' => 'country_name']);
// assumes relation name is country

$city = $profile->city()->create(['name' => 'city_name']);
// assumes relation name is city
```

You can also use `save` method as:

```
$user = Auth::user();

$profile = new Profile;

$user->profile()->save($profile);

$country = new Country;

$profile->country()->save($country);

$city = new City;

$profile->city()->save($city);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `create()` method of the `hasOne` relation to create records associated with this model:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    $user->profile()->create([
        'field' => 'value', // fields that are in the profiles table
    ]);

    $user->country()->create([
        'field' => 'value', // fields that are in the countries table
    ]);

    $user->city()->create([
        'field' => 'value', // fields that are in the cities table
    ]);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Please note that the names of your relations inside the User model are assumed as `city(), country(), profile()`.